# Why is my image jumping back after animation?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to animate a scroll to open and close.
It starts from the closed position and opens just fine but after the animation has completed it jumps back to the closed position.
Here's a link to see a quick video on what it's doing 
http://tinypic.com/r/ieqhkh/8

I'm animating two UIImage views, here's the code to the right image. I thought that setting autoreverse to NO would solve the problem but it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Also, you should post code as text, not a screengrab from your editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067589/580487

```
move.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
move.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

Try removing some other non-required properties as well as a minimum viable product.

Comment: Still jumping back to closed position.

Comment: @user3071579 correct answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13853926/188530