# IOS CABasicAnimation save view to latest position when animation ends

Tags: ios, animation, xamarin

How to save latest position of animated view?

here is my code, generally my aim is to rotate view about 60 degree in z axis.

```
    CABasicAnimation rotationAnimation = new CABasicAnimation ();
    rotationAnimation.KeyPath = "transform.rotation.y";
    rotationAnimation.From = new NSNumber (0);
    rotationAnimation.To = new NSNumber (0.7);
    rotationAnimation.Duration = 5;
    rotationAnimation.AutoReverses = false; 
    rotationAnimation.FillMode = "kCAFillModeForwards";
    rotationAnimation.RemovedOnCompletion = false;  
    this.contentViewContainer.Layer.AddAnimation (rotationAnimation, "rotationAnimation");

    this.contentViewContainer.Layer.ContentsGravity = CALayer.GravityResizeAspectFill;
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3D.Identity;
    nfloat d = (nfloat)(1.0 / 500.0);
    transform.m34 = d;
    this.contentViewContainer.Layer.Transform = transform;
```

here is how it looks
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by latest position? Do you want the View to stay where it is when the animation ends? Do you want the **origin** values?

Comment: exactly , when animation ends

Comment: @ezCoding  have edited my question. have you any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059054/cabasicanimation-resets-to-initial-value-after-animation-completes

Comment: @ezCoding you are right , but this solution doesn't work for me. as you see my code includes this lines:  rotationAnimation.FillMode = "kCAFillModeForwards";
    rotationAnimation.RemovedOnCompletion = false;  what was answers there.

Comment: I'm seeing that you are using a **String** while the other answer used a constant to apply the desired behavior.

Comment: @ezCoding ah great, thanks ^_^  It was my fault . you made my day ^_^

Comment: @ezCoding add this comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059054/cabasicanimation-resets-to-initial-value-after-animation-completes)

You are using a `String` for the `fillMode` and which doesn't have the same value as the **constant** needed here.
So change your code to:

```
rotationAnimation.FillMode = CAFillMode.Forwards
```

Comment: here is correct code line : 
rotationAnimation.FillMode = CAFillMode.Forwards;

Answer (score 0):

simply set:

```
rotationAnimation.AutoReverses = false;
```