# How would I lower the speed of the rotation to 0 in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewanimation

I have this code that rotates my imageview but when I press my pause button I want the rotation speed to be 0. How would I do that?

```
@IBAction func playButtonL(sender: AnyObject) {

    rotation.toValue = NSNumber(double: M_PI * 2)
    rotation.duration = 2
    rotation.cumulative = true
    rotation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
    self.leftCircleImageView.layer.addAnimation(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
}


@IBAction func pauseButtonR(sender: AnyObject) {


}
```

Comment: it works but I have one problem is that it goes back to its original position when it stops. I want it so that it stops at the position its at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Reduce time of animation you can use

> `rotation.duration = 2`

To stop reset it's state default you can use

> `cabasicanimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;`
>
> `cabasicanimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;`

**Answer credits and reference :**

[CABasicAnimation resets to initial value after animation completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059054/cabasicanimation-resets-to-initial-value-after-animation-completes)

Hope it helps! let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: I was putting the code in the wrong button.  I tried all 3 lines of code and the circle keeps rotating.

Comment: Its not stopping at all. I did rotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards and the other two lines of code and it doesnt stop at its final position.

Comment: circle still rotates for some reason. If I add the line self.leftCircleImageView.layer.removeActionWithKey(rotation, "rotationAnimation") it stops but resets to the original position.