# How to solve animation issue when I remove subview from super in Cocoa?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am removing a NSView with animation from view but when the animation finished the blueView appear and then got removed, which makes a bad animation after I did the fade out, here is what I am using:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let blueView: NSView = NSView()
        blueView.wantsLayer = true
        blueView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor

        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        self.view.addSubview(blueView)
        blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blueView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        blueView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(1000)) {
            blueView.fadeAnimation(callBack: { print("Done!"); blueView.alphaValue = 0.0; blueView.removeFromSuperview() })
        }
        
    }

}



extension NSView {
    
    func fadeAnimation(callBack: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let animation = CABasicAnimation()
        
        animation.delegate = CustomCAAnimationDelegate(callBack: callBack)
        animation.keyPath = "opacity"
        animation.duration = 2.0
        animation.fromValue = 1.0
        animation.toValue = 0.0
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
        
        self.layer?.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    }
}




class CustomCAAnimationDelegate: NSObject, CAAnimationDelegate {
    
    var callBack: () -> Void
    
     init(callBack: @escaping () -> Void) {
         self.callBack = callBack
    }
    
    internal func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        callBack()
    }
    
}
```

the goal of this question is removing the view after the fade out animation because there is no need for that also as you can see the used animation is type CABasicAnimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by the accepted answer in this question.

[CABasicAnimation resets to initial value after animation completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059054/cabasicanimation-resets-to-initial-value-after-animation-completes)

The fade animation is missing a little setup

```
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
animation.fillMode = .forwards
```